# Activity order issue

Tags: android

Lets right-away go straight to my problem:

I have three activities: A, B, C.

- Activity A run first, then call B (without finish A).
- After that, B call activity C (without finish B) 
  flag: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. 
  The stack right now likes A - B - C (C is top).
- from C (top now) I call back to activity B with flags
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

So now, the stack likes A - C - B (I say, C is now background for B)

But I want A to be the background for B. (Just like three pictures, and I want picture A is the background for picture B as always)

So is there any way to hide activity C, or reorder it to bottom of stack or any other solution?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, I got a solution, just call back to A before back B :D

Answer (score 0):

[From the Docs:](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a  element inside the . Then specify the parent activity as the value for android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY, matching the android:parentActivityName attribute.

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I try this but It doesn't work, C is still there right after B :(

Comment: What API are you testing on?

Comment: I test on real device firm ware 4.1.2 :D

Comment: What is your min and max SDK?

Comment: Hi, 
Min SDK is 8 
Target SDK is 19

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be to finish activity C while going back to activity B.

```
ActivityC.this.finish();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to finish any because they're running other tasks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

- A (without finish) -> B (without finish)-> C   (Stack = A - B - C)
- C (On Back finish) -> B (Stack = A - B) (C is gone now)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to finish any because they're running other tasks :D

Comment: running other task like what? are you storing any values in variables or what?

Comment: My App is build from modules (each person manage a module). This problem is about bad interacting from each other. And I'm the one who just want to fix this (I'm new to android) :D

Comment: Here is the solution I gave if you can use it Its good otherwise best of luck ;-).